# Bioenergetics of bioconversions: is there a surplus of energy?

Tags: microbiology, theoretical-biology, bioenergetics

By bioconversion, I mean a microbial process during which resting cells are used in order to convert a substrate to a desired product, whithout cell growth. For example, in this [paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00253-005-1895-4), they used *Lactobacillus reuteri* to convert glycerol to 3-hydroxypropionaldehyde, while *L. reuteri* can't grow on glycerol. Basically, during bioconversions, cells produce energy for their metabolism, but do not grow.

The energy thus yielded by cells is supposed to ensure their energetical maintenance cost. **I was wondering what happens to cells if the energy gain is superior to maintenance needs?** Is there some kind of homeostatic regulation of the ATP/ADP ratio? If not, what could be the consequences of too much ATP?

Comment: I am not sure about this pathway that u have mentioned but if u see metabolic regulations of pathways like glycolysis for example or krebs cycle their enzymes are feedback regulated with ATP/ADP ratios.